# DT table downloads hidden column as well

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to exclude downloading columns that is hidden in the DTtable in shiny. Example

```
columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(14))
```

From the above code, 14th columns get hidden. But If I download the table in excel, it downloads this column as well. Can we exclude this?

Currently downloadig like below

```
DT::datatable(df,
                    escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE,selection = 'single',
                    extensions = c('Buttons'),
                    options = list(
                      scrollX = TRUE,
                      paging = TRUE,
                      buttons = c('excel'),
                      columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(2))),                                     
                      pageLength = 400, sScrollY = '40vh',
                      autoWidth = FALSE,
                      buttons = list('copy', 'print',
                                     list(
                                       extend = 'collection',
                                       buttons = c('csv', 'excel'),
                                       text = 'Download'
                                     ))
                    )
      )
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the column in the input dataframe of this DTtable?

Comment: no. That column is needed since based on that columns, other column values are generated

Comment: How are you currently downloading the data?  Posting the full code would help.

Comment: Edited in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
buttons = list(
  list(extend = "excel", exportOptions = list(columns = visibleCols))
)
```

where `visibleCols` is the vector containing the indices of the columns you want to download.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this line. But now the data itself is not displayed :)

Comment: I tried with ````buttons = list(
                        list(extend = c("excel", exportOptions = list(columns = c(2,3)))
                      ))````

Comment: Can you help me?